# Android - Configuring SQLite Tables to meet my needs

Tags: android, mysql, eclipse, sqlite, arraylist

I am having trouble figuring out what to do with my tables.
Scenario -

Recipe Book!

I have a home page with an add button, when clicked on that I add a meal, when meal save button is clicked I add a recipe. Now Here is where it gets tricky.

On my recipe add page I want to be able to Add an ingredient then have the option (Press + button) to add another ingredient, but I am unsure on how to go about this....

Tables Currently:

```
Meal Table
e.g Meal id, meal name

Recipe table
e.g Recipe id, recipe name, Ingredients
```

Now do I have to make a table called Ingredients with 20 columns for a user to be able to put in 20 ingredients or is there a simpler way??

Any help would be great.

EDIT: Silly question

Comment: You should actually have an Ingredients table - which will just contain a list of items (they become ingredients once added to a recipe) - Your  Ingredients won't 20 columns - at least 2 columns (id, and name/description of the item). A recipe should then also include the amount for each ingredient (2 grams for this, 1 gram of that, for instance). You can then have a "join" table that associates an ingredient and its amount with a recipe (e.g MyRecipe-ID, Sugar-Item-ID, 0.5 grams).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By basic Database Principles, multi valued attributes (ingredients in your case) should be placed in a different table with the (ingredient id, recipe id) as the primary key. In this table you can have 3 columns namely recipe id, ingredient id and ingredient name. I hope this is what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. You can [link your ingredients to another table](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) or you can [serialize](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-serialize-arraylist-in-java/) your ingredients list into a single value for storage and deserialize it on retrieval.